# Makefile while loop try/catch equivalent to install python dependencies first with conda then with pip

Tags: makefile, pip, anaconda, gnu-make, conda

I need to run a `while` loop to install Python dependencies. In the Python world recently there are 2 ways to install dependencies which have become established:

- using `conda` (for some people this is the "robust/stable/desired way", provided by a "Python distribution" called Anaconda/Miniconda),
- using `pip` (in the last few years included as the official way of Python itself).

The "pseudocode" should be:

- try to install the dependency with the `conda` command
- if it fails then install it with the `pip` command

In the Python world dependencies are specified in a `requirements.txt` file, usually exact versions (`==`) as one dependency per line with the pattern `<MY_DEPENDENCY>==<MY_VERSION>`.

The equivalent `bash` desired command is: `while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement || pip install $requirement; done < requirements.txt`, however this does not work in the GNU `make`/`Makefile` world for reasons that I don't completely get.

I've tried a few different flavors of that `while` loop - all unsuccessful. Basically once the `conda` command fails I am not able to go on with the `pip` attempt. I am not sure why this happens (as it works in "normal `bash`") and I can not find a way to manage some sort of low-level try/catch pattern (for those familiar with high level programming languages).

This is my last attempt which is not working because it stops when `conda` fails:

```
foo-target:
    # equivalent to bash: conda install --yes $requirement || pip install $requirement;
    while read requirement; do \
        conda install --yes $requirement ; \
        [ $$? != 0 ] || pip install $requirement; \
    done < requirements.txt
```

**How do I make sure I try to install each requirement inside `requirements.txt` first with `conda`, when `conda` fails then with `pip`**?

Why is my code not working? I see people pointing to the differences between `sh` and `bash`, but I am not able to isolate the issue.

**Edit:**

I ended up working around using the `bash` command inside the `Makefile`, but **I find this solution not ideal**, because I need to maintain yet another chunk of code in a one-line bash script (see below), is there a way to keep all the stuff inside a `Makefile` **avoiding `bash` at all**?

The `Makefile` target:

```
foo-target:
    bash install-python-dependencies.sh
```

The `bash` one line script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement || pip install $requirement; done < requirements.txt
```

I can run the script directly from the command line (`bash`), I can also run it from within the `Makefile`, but **I would like to get rid of the bash script and always execute `make foo-target` without using `bash`** (avoiding `bash` even inside the `Makefile`).

Comment: In your recipe double all `$` signs (`$$`) to escape the first expansion by make (before it passes the recipe to the shell). Note: you did this already for `$$?`, do the same for all other `$`signs.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thanks that double dollar `$$` did the trick, I got lost in copy/pasting from many different places without really understanding how Make works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown above, your makefile will work as you expect, other than that you have to escape the `$` in shell variables like `$$requirement`.

I couldn't reproduce your problem with a simplified example to emulate the behavior:

```
foo-target:
        for i in 1 2 3; do \
            echo conda; \
            test $$i -ne 2; \
            [ $$? -eq 0 ] || echo pip; \
        done
```

gives the expected output:

```
$ make
conda
conda
pip
conda
```

Have you added the `.POSIX:` target to your makefile, that you don't show here?  If I do that then I get the behavior you claim to see:

```
conda
make: *** [Makefile:2: foo-target] Error 1
```

The reason for this is described in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) for `.POSIX`:

> In particular, if this target is mentioned then recipes will be invoked as if the shell had been passed the '-e' flag: the first failing command in a recipe will cause the recipe to fail immediately.

If you want to keep `.POSIX` mode but not get this error the simplest way is to use the method you show in your first example; I don't know why you stopped using it:

```
foo-target:
        while read requirement; do \
            conda install --yes $$requirement || pip install $$requirement; \
        done < requirements.txt
```

Comment: Not using `.POSIX`, I was just confusing the single dollar in `bash` with the escaped dollar (double dollar) `$$` in Make. Many thanks

Comment: I can't really explain how that mistake could lead to the behavior you describe (make stopping without running `pip` when `conda` fails).  But it's good you figured it out.  This is why it's always better to show actual error messages and error output (cut and pasted) in questions, rather than using vague descriptions like "this does not work".  Cheers!

Comment: I was experiencing many different errors/unexpected behaviors due to little changes, it might be that with this latest example I put in the question I wasn't seeing an actual error blocking the Make target, however I wasn't seeing `pip` working either (I know some of those requirements live only in `pip` and not in `conda`, so I was expecting them to be installed with `pip`)